# How to avoid OpenShift sub domains being cached by Google?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cloudflare, openshift-online-2

I've set up a custom domain with my OpenShift application. (Which is a blog)
I've setup CloudFlare with page rules to redirect mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com
Now essentially, I've two aliases for my blog in the OpenShift account, namely for mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. And Godaddy pointing to CloudFlare name servers.

But google shows both my domain (www.mydomain.com) and the OpenShift sub url (name-myapp.rhcloud.com). How can I make Google to display results for www.mydomain.com and avoid duplicate listing.

Comment: Set up a 301 redirect.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Should that be done in OpenShift? But I've found no option to do that there?

Comment: @Budhijeevi I have the same situation. Any solution yet?

Comment: Check this answer, specially number 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169529/how-to-use-naked-godaddy-domain-with-openshift-hosting/23178367#23178367